# Working with filtered types with using map / filter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, filter, functional-programming

I realise this question is not specific to typescript, but leaving the below line (B) uncommented would give an error `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'String | Number'`. Is there some way to make it possible for typescript to know that all the elements are now only string (after the filtering is done)?

```
const array_: (String| Number)[] = [99, "Hello, World!"];

array_.map((e) => {if (typeof e === "string") console.log(e.length)}) // A

// array_.filter((e) => typeof e === "string").map((e) => {console.log(e.length)}) // B
```

https://onecompiler.com/typescript/3y88gzecj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you need to use convert `filter` callback to typeguard:

```js
const array_: (String | Number)[] = [99, "Hello, World!"];

array_.map((e) => { if (typeof e === "string") console.log(e.length) }) // A

array_.filter(
  (e): e is string => typeof e === "string").map((e) => {
    console.log(e.length)
  }) // ok
```

Callback `(e): e is string => typeof e === "string"`

Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)
[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4VEw)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so TS knows what you're doing

```
const array_: (String| Number)[] = [99, "Hello, World!"];

const isString = (item: String | Number): item is String => typeof item === "string"

array_.map((e) => {if (typeof e === "string") console.log(e.length)})

array_.filter(isString).map((e) => {console.log(e.length)})
```